# Wordpress- no plug ins work, despite no errors in the console

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have inherited a messy and poorly done custom wordpress theme from another dev. I am not at all an expert with wordpress so I am lost and would love if someone could tell me more about how to fix the issues I have.

No matter what plug in I add whether it is a pop up plug in or Mega Menu plug in, it doesnt work. The page just ignores it but there are no errors in the console. If I adda a drop down menu, it doesnt drop down. It puts it next to it. If I use Pop Up Maker plug in, no pop up etc.

I feel as if there is an issue with the way the theme is calling the .JS library as all of these rely on JS and dont work. The only thing that does work with some .JS is the menu turns white when you scroll down from black. If you want to look, the site is www.fourthwalljobs.com .

In the functions page I have something that appears to be arraying the JS. Here is that function:

```
function denRegScript(){
    wp_enqueue_style( 'datatable-css', get_theme_file_uri('/assets/css/XXX.css'), false );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'datatables-js', get_theme_file_uri('/assets/js/XXX.min.js'), array('jquery'), '0.1', true ); 
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','denRegScript');


add_action('wp_ajax_movie_datatables', 'datatables_server_side_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_movie_datatables', 'datatables_server_side_callback');
//add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_movie_datatables', 'datatables_server_side_callback');
function datatables_server_side_callback()
{
```

JS is called in the footer like so:

```
<!-- Main JS  -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_bloginfo( 'template_directory' );?>/assets/js/jquery-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_bloginfo( 'template_directory' );?>/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Anyone have any ideas of where I can look or add to fix these issues?

Comment: There is a error at your console ---> " datatables.min.js:18 Uncaught TypeError: Bootstrap dropdown require Popper.js ", looks like Popper is missing, i hope that could be the problem. this comes when you click the category dropdown so may be thats blocking the rest of the things from working ?

Comment: Did that answer your problem ?

Comment: https://fourthwalljobs.com/ is the site right ? open console and click the all categories dropdown ?

Comment: This did not solve the issue unfortunately. It is being called correctly and removed that error but makes no difference for the modal plug in. This plug in is being used by 500,000+ so I know it works

Comment: where is the modal plugin? click on what opens the modal plugin ?

Comment: It is an auto load modal that should open as soon as you visit the page. I would be looking at that plug in only but the Mega Menu doesnt work and regular menus dont work either without the plug in. I am unable to do a dropdown menu